# Trying to select an <img> in css and change the size

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So what I'm trying to do is select an img tag and change the size of it, I tried to use a class selector and id but they don't seem to work, I got this to work locally but as soon as I upload it to the server the css doesn't take effect

html

```
<div id="logo3">
  <img src="img/fehr.png" alt="logo">
</div>
```

css I tried but doesn't work:

```
img[src="img/fehr.png"] { 
  height: 90px; 
  width: auto;
}
img[alt~="logo"] { 
  height: 90px; 
  width: auto;
}
#logo3 { 
  height: 90px; 
  width: auto; 
}
```

css that works:

```
img { height: 90px; width: auto; }
```

but I want to use a selector incase I add more images later.

Comment: You are not targeting the image itself, `#logo3` will target the div. You should place a class or id on the `<img>`: `<img class="logo">` and the css `.logo { /*styles*/ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try

```
#logo3 img{
    height: 90px; width: auto;
}
```

Or with Jquery

```
$('#logo3 img').css('height','90');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ...

html

```
<div id="logo3"><img src="img/fehr.png" alt="logo"></div>
```

css

```
img[src="img/fehr.png"] {
     height: 100px;
     width: auto;
     background-color: red;
}
```

> //the other two also works

Try adding '!important' on the end, and check if nothing overwrite your css.

```
img[src="img/fehr.png"] {
     height: 100px!important;
     width: auto!important;
     background-color: red!important;
}
```

Comment: Something has to overwrite your css. It works perfectly when i tested it. Perhaps other css file or some javascript/Jquery script